# svn publisher jenkins plugin usage

Tags: svn, plugins, jenkins

I need to backup some files from the ci server (apache settings, jenkins settings, tomcat settings, job xml files)

I wrote a job that copies a bunch of files to job workspace

after the build i want to publish the changes to svn repo

I specified url, workspace dir, and i want all folder/files
so I tried using * **/*.* as regex
but the thing does not commit any files

help?

```
SVN Publisher: target: /SYSAPPS/ci/jenkinsjava/jobs/config-backup/workspace
SVN Publisher: Error: target Directory not accessable:  /SYSAPPS/ci/jenkinsjava/jobs/config-backup/workspace
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: And your Jenkins home directory is called `jenkinsjava`? Also, are you sure you are running on master node and not on a slave?

Comment: Its running on windows with apache, tomcat and jdk 1.6, yes its jenkins java and its master (no slaves configured on that box)

Comment: our repo requires authentication, looks like this plugin is not for prime time use yet